# Click event on custom control in list view not always setting SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a situation where I have a listview :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEnvironment}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:RadioButtonTextBox DataContext="{Binding}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

which uses a custom control as its item template:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:StringCompareToBooleanConverter}">
                <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>    
    </RadioButton>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource RedTextBlock}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the problem I have is that if the user clicks on the textblock of the custom control then the correct thing happens, i.e. the item is selected (and the view model updates accordingly), yet if the user click on the radio button of the custom control the radio button becomes checked but the selected item is not updated and the previously selected item does not get deselected.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The click is handled and not propagated by your radio button.

In cases where the item contains input elements i tend to bind `IsSelected` in the `ItemContainerStyle` to `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`. Not sure if this deselects the old item, maybe only if selection mode is `Single`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found was to simply set the enabled flag on the radio button to false:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:StringCompareToBooleanConverter}">
                <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>    
    </RadioButton>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource RedTextBlock}"/>
</StackPanel>
```